# How to get a line as a structuring element in openCv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image and I want to perform **closing** on that image with the **line** as structuring element. 
The openCv api has a function **getStructuringElement** that takes the following parameters

- Shape
- Size
- Anchor Point

I can pass **CV_SHAPE_CUSTOM** in the first parameter to create a new shape but where do I 
pass the **size** and the **values** of my structuring element.

My line will be 10 pixels wide and 1 pixels in length basically {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}.

There is an old function **createStructringElementEx** but I don't want to use that as it involves a lot of conversion of datatype.

Comment: Why don't you just draw a line using `cv::line()`? Or, if it's a straight line, just draw it using a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it . Thanks to the comment from Niko.

Create a matrix as

```
Mat line = Mat::ones(1,10,CV_8UC1);
//now apply the morphology close operation
morphologyEx(img, img, MORPH_CLOSE, line,Point(-1,-1));
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Size = Size(10,1)

Anchor Point = Point(-1,-1)